# Specify the width and alignment of tabular column at the same time

Tags: tables, columns, width, alignment

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}c}
  A0 &  A1\\
  BBB00 &   BBB111
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

Using `p{3cm}` allowed me to specify the column width, but chose left alignment by default. How can I additionally control also the alignment of the first column (e.g. centred)?

Comment: Load `array` and use `>{\centering}p{3cm}`

Answer (score 3):

`p` is justified rather than left aligned, Assuming you have the `array` package loaded you could use

```
>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm}
```

to get a ragged right p box, but for data tables you don't really want a p column with aligned paragraphs so with current `array` package you can use

```
wc{3cm}
```

for a 3cm wide c column.